# Windows Server 2008, восстановить файл

Tags: windows, windows-server

Такой вопрос, удалил папку неделю назад, в ней были файлы, сейчас нужно было восстановить её, открыл корзину там есть все файлы кроме одного, он весил больше 5гб, и соответственно удалился безвозвратно

Вопрос, есть ли вариант восстановить его, без восстановления всей системы?

Стоит Windows Server 2008, уже перезагружался. **После удаления был создан файл с точно таким же названием.**

Архивы сервера писались, но хранятся 1 день, соответственно ничего нету

Прогой для восстановления пробовал, она показывается все мои 130к файлов удалённых, и папку которую я удалил, но нужного файла там нету, есть вариант что он теперь где то в другом месте хранится?
Какая вообще логика когда файл удаляешь без возвратно, он частично стирается с диска или в какой то другой формат переходит или сразу же навсегда стирается? Имя файла сохраняется навсегда в системе?

Comment: `удалил папку неделю назад`. Дальше не читал. Добро пожаловать в ряды тех, кто теперь БУДЕТ ДЕЛАТЬ бэкапы.

Answer (score 0):

При удалении файла в файловой системе NTFS его имя исключается из индекса родительского каталога, а соответствующая ему запись [MFT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_File_Table) («Master File Table») и занимаемые им кластеры освобождаются. Происходит пересортировка индекса, в результате которой информация об имени файла может быть утеряна. Соответственно, имя удалённого файла более не будет присутствовать в исходном каталоге.

MFT хранит все записи в одной таблице.
Для того чтобы восстановить удалённые в NTFS файлы, необходимо просканировать MFT в поиске свободных записей. При обнаружении свободной записи становится возможным определить имя файла – оно хранится в одном из атрибутов.

Имя файла удаётся определить не всегда. Зато в отличие от файловой системы FAT указатели на кластеры, занимаемые удалённым файлом, продолжают существовать. Соответственно, удаётся восстановить файл любого размера и любой степени фрагментации – разумеется, при условии, что **занимаемые им кластеры не были перезаписаны другими данными.**

В вашем случае MFT просто указывает на новый файл с таким же именем, расположенный в других кластерах и поиск по MFT не поможет.